# How to edit CSV data in C# like 1234567 to 123-4567?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csv, webforms

Im trying to edit a postcode data which comes as for example 1234567 and i want to put a dash between 123 and 4567 (e.g 123-4567) is it possible to do this within C# without editing the csv file itself?

Im using a generic for loop to read through the csv file but i want to edit it like i asked above.

```
                foreach(string line in csvData_){
                string[] col = line.Split(',');
                deliveryAddress.Text = col[0];
                deliveryPostcode.Text = col[1];
```

deliveryPostcode contains 1234567 for e.g.

Comment: do you want to change the data in CSV itself? or you want to change only while displaying?

Comment: @Chetan  Change only while displaying to the screen yes!

Comment: can you share the code which displays the data from CSV to UI?

Comment: well, if such simplest task is "impossible" in c#, there is no need to invent any programming languages.

Comment: @Chetan there you go.

Comment: @AIMINPAN thanks for the wonderful reply. youre such a lifesaver.

Comment: Try using substring method of string to get the first and second part of the string and concate them with `-` in between..

Comment: @DannyMelander you may wish to look into [substrings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-substring-method/), but for more flexibility, it would be good for you to study [regular expressions](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-regex-examples/). Regexp's can validate postcodes, and works also if the postcode is "sometimes this, but other cases that".

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KwXtmX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, you can use the method `Insert()` of the string object.
For example:

```
deliveryPostcode.Text = col[1].Length == 7 ? col[1].Insert(3, "-") : col[1];
```

You have to fit it for your needs, but this is the way I would use.

Here is the [MSDN page of the `String.Insert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Mind, though: _"ArgumentOutOfRangeException - startIndex is negative or greater than the length of this instance."_ - never trust user input, which I would consider a csv file to be.

Comment: @Fildor You got a point ! Thank you for your comment, I updated my answer